# Python path string not found by os.path and dataframe.to_csv

Tags: python, string, export-to-csv, filepath

I try to sort some files, hence I first read all csv-files in a directory, sort them and then save them again in a different directory path. However, there seems to be an issue with creating the path strings because they can not be processed anymore by the libraries.

The following code results in an error: 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Daten/NoEncaps/4-point-empty-pcb/sorted/T10/emptyPCB-T30RH30''. You might ask yourself why the code is so strange: I already tried to fix it. For example, before there were backslashes (\) instead of slashes - if I printed my outputpath to the console everything was fine (C:\Users\user...) but as soon as I attempted to use os.mkdir(...) or dataframe.to_csv(...) It gave the same error message justwith all backslashes being replaced by double backslashes. Deleting the part with the mkdir does not help as well.

Thanks for all constructive feedback in advance!

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as p

path = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\Daten\NoEncaps\4-point-empty-pcb"
path_file = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\Daten\NoEncaps\4-point-empty-pcb\emptyPCB-T30RH30\Transfer_emptyPCB_C2 PLSTA T101__T_RT_2018-07-09 11_28_30_(1.1).csv"

(head,tail) = os.path.split(path_file)


#data = pd.read_csv(path_file, sep = ';')
d = {'FETname':['C2 PLSTA T10']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


head = head.replace(path,'')
head = head.replace('\\','')
fetname = data[['FETname']].loc[0].to_string()
groupname = ''
if 'C2 PLSTA T10' in fetname:
    groupname = 'T10'

outputpath = os.path.join(path,"sorted",groupname,head)
fullout = os.path.join(outputpath,tail)
outputpath = p.posixpath.join(*outputpath.split('\\'))
fullout = p.posixpath.join(*fullout.split('\\'))
print(fullout)
if not os.path.exists(outputpath):
    os.mkdir(outputpath)

data.to_csv(fullout, sep = ';')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `os.makedirs()` to create trees of directories; `os.mkdir()` can only create them one directory deep, as it were.

Maybe something like this? I've changed the backslashes to forward slashes, as Python is rather graceful about those cross-platform.

```
import os.path

root_path = r"C:/Users/user/Documents/Daten/NoEncaps/4-point-empty-pcb"
# NB: this is relative to `root_path`.
path_file = r"emptyPCB-T30RH30/Transfer_emptyPCB_C2 PLSTA T101__T_RT_2018-07-09 11_28_30_(1.1).csv"

head, tail = os.path.split(path_file)

data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root_path, path_file))
fetname = data[['FETname']].loc[0].to_string()

# Generate the path out of components...
components = ['sorted']

if 'C2 PLSTA T10' in fetname:
    components.append(groupname)

components.append(head)
output_dir = os.path.join(*[root_path] + components)

if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    print("Creating", output_dir)
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, tail)

print("Writing to", output_file)

data.to_csv(fullout, sep = ';')
```

Comment: Thanks - makedirs was the important part that solved the error :D however, when I try to introduce the other stuff for a better style it does not work. The join command then buggs out and parths of the path get cut out...

Answer (score -2):

as i see, the problem in string of path.
replace "\" to "\\"
it could help because the character "\" using for format string

Comment: No, the OP used `r'...'` raw string literals, where backslashes only have meaning when used with a `'` or `"` quote character.